# How to implement Client Credential Flow with Azure AD as Identity provider for Cognito

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

We have an application hosted on AWS using Cognito Service, with Azure AD acting as the Identity provider. The solution works great with username and password, authenticating against the Cognito user pool.

We now need the above to work for service-to-service call scenario.

The unattended scheduled service will call another service (all hosted in AWS) but will need to authenticate with access token.
I was thinking of using client credential flow. But I could not find an approach which will work for the above scenario (i.e) client credential flow with Cognito using Azure AD as Identity provider.

When I go Azure AD Application Registration and view the endpoints, the oauth2/token endpoint shows up, but I have not figured out how this will work with Cognito.

Does any one know how to implement this?

Comment: something like this? https://medium.com/@zippicoder/setup-aws-cognito-user-pool-with-an-azure-ad-identity-provider-to-perform-single-sign-on-sso-7ff5aa36fc2a

Comment: Thanks @NinadGaikwad for the link to detailed article.  However, it deals with Authorisation code grant and Implict grant flow. I need an approach for Client credentials flow, such that service to service calls can get authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cognito if you use client credentials flow, there will not be any federated Identity provider involved. There will be no users so no need to use Azure AD to generate tokens. You will make the access request using Client Id and Client Secret and will be granted an access token that you can use.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-user-pool-oauth-2-0-grants/